# Localhost/mywebsite redirecting to www.mywebsite.co.uk

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website, which runs on a Linux server.  I had to rebuild my Windows PC recently so I am trying to migrate the website from www.mywebsite.co.uk (Linux) to localhost (Windows).  I have followed all of the instructions in this video: [wordpress on localhost linked to live site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906585/wordpress-on-localhost-linked-to-live-site) i.e.

1) PHPMyAdmin: Export MySQL database from live website and import it to MySQL on localhost.

2) Filezilla: Download website files over FTP

3) Run SQL statements in the answer from this question: [wordpress on localhost linked to live site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906585/wordpress-on-localhost-linked-to-live-site)

4) Change username, password and hostname in wp_config

5) Add the two define statements from here to the wp-config: [wordpress on localhost linked to live site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906585/wordpress-on-localhost-linked-to-live-site)

6) Used this tool: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Still when I browse to my site: http://localhost/mysite; it redirects to [www.mysite.co.uk](http://www.mysite.co.uk).  Is there anything else I can do? Could it be the theme?

Update
I have made the following changes to my wp-config:

```
defin( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost' ); //was www.mysite.co.uk
```

define( 'MULTISITE', false ); //was true

I can now access my homepage and admin (wp-admin).  However, when I click on other links e.g. About Me, Site Index etc; I get a 404 error.

Comment: You've hurried up with down-vote ... I was going to paste in the additional steps (posted too early by mistake), but it seems you don't need them ... good luck.

Comment: @CodrutTG, what do you mean by: "You've hurried up with down-vote"? Thanks.

Comment: @CodrutTG, are you saying your additional steps are posted in my question.  If they are not, then I do want to see them! Not sure what you mean.

Comment: He's saying you should be patient before downvoting a comment, or people will get mad and it will hurt you in the end

Comment: @131, fair enough.  However, he/she just posted some steps I have already taken, which I also specified in my question.  I see downvotes on here all the time for that.  I did this once because the poster edited their questions seconds before I posted and I received three downvotes.

Comment: have you check database? Is it updated and URL changed from live site to localhost?

Comment: @w0051977: update permalink from admin section and make sure your .haccess at root folder should working.switch permalink from ?p=id to /%postname%/ and check it.No need to define localhost in wp-config.php as well.

Comment: @Ash Patel, the admin panel is not working now (it was before).  I tried chaning the password using these instructions: https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password.  Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to login to msql and change password manually? set type MD5 for password as mentioned in instruction...

Comment: @Ash Patel, how is that different to using PHPMyAdmin? I will try it though.

Comment: Let's chat ..so we can solve your problem quickly..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135443/discussion-between-ash-patel-and-w0051977).

Comment: @Ash Patel, now I can access the wp-admin but not the homepage (or the rest of the site).  Any ideas?

Comment: What is an error at front end?

Comment: @Ash Patel, Firefox says: "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: Have you removed WP_SITEURL from wp-config.php?

Comment: @Ash Patel, other posts tell mne to add this.  However, I have removed it and still the same problem.

Comment: @Ash Patel, there are 20 HTTP 301s.

Comment: so now redirection is not happening and front end stop loading ...

Comment: @Ash Patel, it would appear so.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: let's chat about current issue..

Comment: About the 404 issue, you may have custom URL enabled. In that case, you need to make sure `.htaccess` is copied to your localhost and Apache settings allow `.htaccess` to override configs.

Comment: @Ash Patel, I have got a bit further.  I have asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179354/wordpress-configuration-issue-on-local-pc.  Could you take a look if you get chance?

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress remembers the domain that you installed it in. You need to explicitly tell it to change the default domain.

Please read the Wordpress codex:  [Changing the Site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

P.S. I believe you're doing this as an intermediate step in your migration,  right? There is no way for people outside to access your site with http://localhost

Comment: Thanks +1 for the link.  I am migrating to localhost so that I can test my website on my local PC.  Please see the update to my question.  There is no reference to DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE in your link.

Comment: I used `update_option` routine and it worked for my case. I weren't using multisite it my case anyway.

Comment: Just the routine he codex refer as **Edit functions.php**